# discord.js send and wait before editing a message

Tags: javascript, wait, discord.js

I want my bot, to send `my emotes`, wait 1 seconds and edit the message to `my others emotes`.

Here's my code :

```
message.channel.send('my emotes')
  .then((msg) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
    msg.edit('my other emotes');
  }, 1000)});
```

And he send me this error : `Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined`

Thanks you for helping me.

Comment: Seems fine to me. The code should work as expected.

Comment: I just tested your code and works fine. What NodeJS version you have? And what discord.js version? Use `node -v` to get Node version and `npm list discord.js` to get the discordjs version

Comment: finaly, I've managed myself and I patched it, if finaly works !

Comment: You should answer your own question with that you did to make it work, so if anyone else is having the same issue as you know what you did to solve it. @Dillgo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so finaly the code that works is :

```
message.channel.send('my emote')
.then((msg)=> {
  setTimeout(function(){
    msg.edit('my others emotes');
  }, 1000)
});
```