# Getting error when trying to edit my bot message with discord.js

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I want to edit a message the bot send.

And i think i've found how to do it but my editor says that .edit does not exist on type message[].

What did I do wrong?

```
   msgObject.channel.send('my emote').then((msg)=>{
   setTimeout(function(){
   msg.edit('my others emotes');}, 1000)};
```

Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My code works fine:

```
message.channel.send("test").then(msg => { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        msg.edit('new test'); 
    }, 5000) 
});
```

Perhaps your `msg` is causing your error, so try changing it to something else.
Also, your code has bracket issues (not enough closing brackets).

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840290/discord-js-send-and-wait-before-editing-a-message), it was suggested maybe your Discord.js or NodeJS is out of date, which may result in an error. [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840290/discord-js-send-and-wait-before-editing-a-message#comment86695954_49840290)

Answer (score 0):

My code works:

```
msgObject.channel.send('My message').then(msg =>{
   setTimeout(() => {
      if(msg instanceof Message){
         msg.edit('My other message')
      }
   }, 1000)
})
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards

Answer (score 0):

your `message.channel.send("test")`message seems to be returning an array of messages. Therefor you need to first select one of the messages. [if you look on the docs you can see that it either returns a message or a message array](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send). why this is the case i wouldn't have a clue but hope you can go further from there.